# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, aurelia

I'm trying to build my Aurelia project after add ag-grid and I get this error.
I'm in OSX 10.14.
I have tried this in the .bash_profile

`NODE_OPTIONS="–max-old-space-size=4096`
but still fails
Any idea please
Regards

Comment: Just a follow up, have you been able to resolve this? If you have, can you post the answer here? It'd be super helpful to others.

Comment: I have not resolve this problem I'm still locked with this and I'm working with a virtual machine with Windows 10 where I have not this problem

Comment: Today the same problem in Windows I'm desperate I can not work

Comment: So it happens to you after awhile? If this is a correct assumption, I imagine there is something wrong with your dependencies / cache?

Comment: I have freed the excessive use of locales when importing Moment following this steps: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/webpack/ and now The project in OSX can au build. With the same RAM but this in Windows stills fails.

Comment: May I know are you using webpack or cli built-in bundler?

Comment: Nvm, I guess it is webpack based on the article you redering.

Comment: I'm using webpack